# Convert Scalar to double in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with openCv, i have achieved a Scalar value  by using:

```
Scalar scal = trace(r[i]); // vector<Mat> r[10];
```

How do i convert scal variable to double value? because i want to caculate R[i] matrix follow the formula:

```
 R{i} = ((r{i}*r{i}')/trace(r{i}*r{i}'));
```

Please help me, thank in advance!

Comment: Scalar is a 4 element vector and you can access these elements using scal.val[i] . Trace should lie under scal.val[0]

Comment: Thank's Canberk,  it is true and i have resolved.